# Angular-Keycloak Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Class constructor KeycloakAuthGuard cannot be invoked without 'new' TypeError:

Tags: angular, keycloak

Friends, I want to connect my keycloak server with Angular, but I cannot do this and I cannot find any new resources. Can you help me?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular?activeTab=readme I also used the resources on this site, but even though I watched the videos in some parts, it gives errors even though I do the same things.Even though the resource appears to be new, when I try to use it, it is already protected readonly router: Router,
protected readonly keycloak: KeycloakService I get errors in these parts. const requiredRoles = route.data.roles;
I am experiencing an error in the roles section in this section as well. I would appreciate it if you could help me. There may be a new resource among other users.

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { KeycloakAngularModule, KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: 'http://localhost:8080',
        realm: 'codelabs',
        clientId: 'cosmos-web'
      },
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
          window.location.origin + '/assets/silent-check-sso.html'
      }
    });
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [AppRoutingModule, BrowserModule, KeycloakAngularModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService] 
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  Router,
  RouterStateSnapshot
} from '@angular/router';
import { KeycloakAuthGuard, KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard extends KeycloakAuthGuard {
  constructor(
    protected override readonly router: Router,
    protected readonly keycloak: KeycloakService
  ) {
    super(router, keycloak);
  }

  public async isAccessAllowed(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ) {
    // Force the user to log in if currently unauthenticated.
    if (!this.authenticated) {
      await this.keycloak.login({
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + state.url
      });
    }

    // Get the roles required from the route.
    const requiredRoles = route.data['roles']; //As I mentioned above, when I set the role section to this with the automatic solution, there is no problem, but I am not sure how accurate it is.

    // Allow the user to proceed if no additional roles are required to access the route.
    if (!Array.isArray(requiredRoles) || requiredRoles.length === 0) {
      return true;
    }

    // Allow the user to proceed if all the required roles are present.
    return requiredRoles.every((role) => this.roles.includes(role));
  }
}

export function keycloakGuard(arg0: RouterStateSnapshot | ActivatedRouteSnapshot): any {
  throw new Error('Function not implemented.');
}
```

[image: I'm getting an error like this]

I watched many videos on this subject and searched on stack overflow and couldn't find anything new.

Comment: this post is a bit old, but it does mention something about adding to the `routes`. https://medium.com/@damilareaadedoyin/authentication-in-angular-using-keycloak-aff8e98dd094 . And this post is a bit newer, which discusses the `initializer` - https://plainenglish.io/blog/secure-an-angular-single-page-application-with-keycloak-cdbe5026881e